# What are the alternatives for "If I were you"?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, phrases, questions, spoken-english

What alternative phrases should I use for "If I were you" / "If I was you"?

Is there any alternative to say the above-mentioned phrase?

Are the below sentences can be used as alternatives:

- If I'm you
- If I'm in your position etc.

Comment: I frequently use "**If it were me,**" but maybe that's too similar.

Comment: In your situation, I  would...

Comment: You certainly can't say 'If I'm you', because obviously you are not the other person!

Comment: In your situation/circumstances, I would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are the below sentences can be used as alternatives:
>
> • If I'm you
>
> •If I'm in your position etc.

No, your alternatives are not correct.

To describe imaginary or hypothetical situations, we use a past tense in the **if clause**.

Remember, it’s incorrect to use *I am you* in the if-clause because we never use “present tense” in unreal conditionals

> What alternative phrases should I use for "If I were you" / "If I was you"?

There are no alternatives.

Remember, we use “if I was” when we are talking about a possibility that did happen or might be true.

And we use “if I were” when a sentence is in the subjunctive mood (indicating an imaginary situation).

Therefore, It’s correct to say **if I were you** because it’s a hypothetical situation. (I am not you but if I were you...)

Answer (score 0):

"If I was you" is always wrong.

"were" in this context is not the plural form of "was", it is the subjunctive version.

"If I was" refers to a statement about things that happened in the past:

"If I was slow yesterday, I will be even slower today" is correct, because the writer is referring to something which was possible. Was he slow yesterday? Perhaps.

"If I was you" would suggest that there is the possibility that the writer *was* actually you, but this did not happen and so is incorrect.

"If I were you, ..." actually means, "In the strictly hypothetical situation where I am you ..." which of course is not actually possible because I am *not* you and can never be you.

But to answer the question, "In your position" is a good synonym for "if I were you".

Or possibly (more colloquially) "In your shoes".